# Creating a factorial subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl, subroutine, factorial

I'm a first-time poster and a new programmer.

I'm trying to create a program that will take all the multiples of 3 and 5 that are less than a thousand and then add them together for a final sum.

I'm practicing subroutines and so I'm trying to use a single subroutine where I just feed it either 3 or 5.

I feel like I'm close, but it keeps returning endless zeros, so I have to Ctrl-C out of the script.

Another problem I'm having is that the array is receiving 1000 (in the case of 5's) and 1002 (in the case of 3's). How can I stop numbers 1000 or higher being put in the array?

I want to start practicing recursion. Would recursion be a more appropriate solution to this problem?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

sub multiples;


my $sum_threes = multiples(3);
my $sum_fives = multiples(5);

my $total_sum = $sum_threes + $sum_fives;
print $total_sum, "\n";


sub multiples {
    my $input_number;
    my $sum_number = 0;
    my $count_number = 0;
    my @count_array;

    while ($count_number < (1000 - $input_number)) {
        $count_number += $input_number;
        push(@count_array, $count_number);
        print "$_\n" for @count_array;
    }
    foreach (@count_array) {
        $sum_number += $_;
    }
    print "Total sum of factorial for multiples of $input_number is $sum_number.\n";
    return $sum_number;
}
```

Comment: You have clearly started learning from somewhere, and that somewhere doesn't seem to be too reliable. You should always `use warnings` (right after `use strict`) in preference to `-w` on the shebang line. You *must* also learn to indent your code properly. Opinions vary, but everything inside a block should be indented by between two and four spaces relative to the code outside the block. A look at [`perldoc perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) would help you a lot.

Comment: You should clarify your question to get meaningful answers. Your problem description and code doesn't have anything to do with factorials. I suggest you to narrow your question to a more specific problem (e.g. "why doesn't this loop stop?"

Answer (score 4):

Programming is about implementing an [*algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) in a programming language. You should concentrate on the tools and facilities that the language offers you rather than the algorithm that you are trying to implement.

You have made a fairly trivial mistake in your Perl code: the variable `$input_number` is never assigned a value. A Perl subroutine receives the parameters that are passed to it in the built-in array `@_`, and you can set `$input_number` to the first value passed in by writing

```
my $input_number = shift;
```

If you make just that change then you will see that your program now *does something*. But what it doesn't do is calculate a factorial, because your *algorithm* is wrong. After all, the factorial of 3 is 3 × 2 × 1 = 6, and there is nothing in there to do with the value 1000.

I would help you to fix this, but you are aiming way too high for a first program. For now, here are some suggestions based on your code that will help you to see through the forest.

- It may seem helpful to use long, meaningful names for your variables. But in fact, if the names are too long then they hide the structure of the program. Keep your identifiers down to, say, under ten characters
- As well as being concise, variable names should be *meaningful*. Your `$count_number` and `@count_array` are nothing to do with counts: `$count_number` is a value calculated by adding successive multiples of `$input_number`, and `@count_array` is a list of those values
- Use `for` instead of `foreach` for the same reason. They are identical
- Write subroutines to perform intermediate operations based on their parameters. Leave it up to the caller to decide what to do with the results. In particular, a subroutine shouldn't usually have a `print` statement unless it is for debugging purposes

Here's how I would write the code that you posted. It still doesn't work, but I hope you can see that it's more readable than the original. What it *actually* does is to calculate a bizarre fraction of 1000<sup>2</sup>, but to fix that you need to fix the *algorithm*.

I hope you can see the value of indentation, and shorter, but still meaningful variable names?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum_threes = multiples(3);
print "Total sum of factorial for multiples of 3 is $sum_threes.\n";

my $sum_fives  = multiples(5);
print "Total sum of factorial for multiples of 3 is $sum_fives.\n";

my $total_sum = $sum_threes + $sum_fives;
print $total_sum, "\n";

sub multiples {

    my $number = shift;

    my @values;

    my $value = $number;
    while ( $value < 1000 ) {
        push @values, $value;
        $value += $number;
    }

    my $sum = 0;
    $sum += $_ for @values;

    return $sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reply!  The reason I'm taking on so much is I was an MIS major in school but recently was hired on full-time to maintain and develop Perl code, so I'm trying to catch up.  I noticed my mistake in not passing the value to my subroutine through "shift" last night, but I'm still not sure how to fix my algorithm.  Any tips?  As is it loops through and does multiples of five correctly, but doesn't touch multiples of threes.

Comment: @flybonzai: Well your algorithm is so far from calculating a factorial that I wonder whether that is really what you intended to do. I'm sure you could fix it yourself if I explain. What you're doing is calculating a *sum of multiples*, so `multiples(3)` returns `3 + 6 + 9 + 12 + ... + 999`, whereas a *factorial* is a product of a series, so `factorial(3)` is `1 × 2 × 3` and `factorial(5)` is `1 × 2 × 3 × 4 × 5`. Does that give you enough of a hint?

Comment: you are exactly right, I'm trying to create a sum of multiples as opposed to a factorial.

Answer (score 1):

Top level answer: you're taking on too much. Learn to write a simple loop that counts from 1 to 10 and prints out the values; learn to write a simple subroutine that receives a parameter and uses it for something trivial; learn to write a simple program that takes the values from an array and adds them together.

What does this have to do with factorial?!

To get specific:

1. Your indentation is off. Code is nearly impossible to read without correct indentation. I had to look at it six times to make any sense of it.

"No computation without indentation"

2. Your loop logic is missing a key ingredient: the "progress" or "increment" step. Both $count_number and $input_number never change within the loop body, so the condition at the top of the loop will never change truth value.
3. There are other logic problems such as not actually distinguishing whether $count_number is actually a multiple of anything before adding it.
4. You should name your parameters, e.g.:

   ```
   my $mult_value = shift;
   ```

at the top of the subroutine.

6. Re: recursion: No. Of course it's possible. But pedagogically: Take. It. Slow.

Good luck!

Comment: *"Both `$count_number` and `$input_number` never change within the loop body"* except for `$count_number += $input_number`

Comment: Adding zero doesn't count as change :-) It's helpful to explain why the OP's *code as posted* loops indefinitely.

Comment: Okay, well if that was intentional then I think you're being too cryptic for a complete beginner. `$input_number` is never defined, so it's left set to `undef`, which evaluates as zero in an addition but also raises a warning.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 3. `$count_number` is a value that starts at zero and has `$input_number` added to it repeatedly. So it must always be a multiple of `$input_number`. What are the other logic problems that you found?

Comment: Re: logic, by the title of the question, this fails to calculate any sort of factorial. As far as not being a multiple, I think I was thrown off by the undefined variable and just what it was *supposed* to be tied to.

Comment: Not achieving its purpose isn't a *logic error*. And the parameter was clearly supposed to be `$input_number`. So we're left with 1. Indent properly and 2. Don't look at recursion yet. I would agree with those two.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but "factorial" made me think of Mark Jason Dominus's [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) which is an excellent book (recommended if you can still find it). It jumps right into writing simple and powerful functions start to blow your mind on page 2 and just keep right on going till page 500.  Here is his factorial subroutine from page 5:

```
sub factorial {
  my ($n) = @_;
  return 1 if $n == 0;
  return factorial($n-1) * $n;
}
```

HOP was a treasure trove of ideas when I wanted to stretch my mind beyond the "procedural perl" that becomes habit when you spend your time replacing shell scripts with perl versions thereof. Kudos to MJD.

Comment: I downloaded the PDF, that book looks like a great resource!